# PayPal Payflow + E-Commerce: Is it against standards to save the last 4 digits of a CC?

Tags: e-commerce, paypal

I am using the PayPal Payflow API for my Rails app and I know you're not supposed to save the whole credit card info, but I noticed that the response PayPal sends back contains the card type, last 4 CC digits, and expiration date, so I'm wondering if it's okay to save this info since I want my site to be able to "remember the user's CC info" after the first purchase so that it shows ***********1111 on the CC field and populates the CC fields for a smoother 2nd purchase.

PayPal's response:

> {"RESULT"=>"0", "PNREF"=>"A71A5F4CDF90", "RESPMSG"=>"Verified",
>   "AUTHCODE"=>"153PNI", "AVSADDR"=>"Y", "AVSZIP"=>"Y", "CVV2MATCH"=>"Y",
>   "HOSTCODE"=>"A", "PROCAVS"=>"Y", "PROCCVV2"=>"M",
>   "TRANSTIME"=>"2014-01-30 06:55:25", "FIRSTNAME"=>"ffff",
>   "LASTNAME"=>"theory", "AMT"=>"0.00", "ACCT"=>"5100",
>   "EXPDATE"=>"1215", "CARDTYPE"=>"1", "IAVS"=>"N"}

Not sure if this question belongs in stackoverflow. Forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the whole card number if you want but PCI compliance forbids you to save the CVV2 (see [this PDF](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3.pdf), page 8). I log the last 4 myself without issue and some gateways actually require you to reference the last 4 when you do things like tokenization.

You don't have to actually store their info if you want to reprocess a card. This is one area where Classic, as opposed to REST, can help. Check out [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) for more information